# Cannot create a react native app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, sudo

The Steps to create a react native app:

1. `npm install -g create-react-native-app`
2. `create-react-native-app my-app`
3. `cd my-app`

I have completed the first step but I'm stuck in the second step since yesterday.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtBYj.png)

PS:  Yes, I use sudo because somehow, the NPM have security problems.

Comment: use npm version 4

Comment: Have you killed the process and tried to run npm install by yourself in that folder?

Comment: This may be a problem with fs.inotify.max_user_watches limit. You can try to increase it. May be start with 50000 echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=xxxxxx | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p

Comment: What version of Node are you running? Also, might be useful to run `npm cache clean` before running `create-react-native-app my-app` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As per docs](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app#quick-overview)

> Make sure you have Node v6 or later installed

Can you please check it by executing

```
node --version
```